# how to add pause at end of function before moving on

Tags: jquery

I tried posting this earlier, but it was voted to be closed. Yes, I have read related topics and cannot figure it out, which is why Im asking the question.

I have a ul that has several li's. The li's fade in, and when the last one fades in the list fades out and the next ul fades its li's in. I want to add a delay so that when the last li of each ul fades in it pauses before fading out and moving onto the next list.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    ...etc
</ul>
//several other <ul> with same markup
```

JS

```
function AnimateList($listItems, index, callback) {
    if (index >= $listItems.length) {
        $listItems.closest("ul.contracts").fadeOut(function() {
            $listItems.css("left","400px").css("opacity",0); //reset
            callback(); //next list
        });
        return;
    }

    $listItems.eq(index).animate({left:0, opacity:1}, 1500, function() {
        AnimateList($listItems, index+1, callback)
    });
}

function FadeLists($lists, index) {
    if (index >= $lists.length) index = 0;
    var $currentList = $lists.eq(index);
    $currentList.fadeIn(function() {
        AnimateList($currentList.find("li"), 0, function() { FadeLists($lists, index + 1) });
    })
}

var $allLists = $("ul.contracts")
FadeLists($allLists, 0);
```

I have tried using setTimeout(), delay(), and an .each function but nothing works. Also, I don't understand the use of 'callback' here. Again, I have read similar questions but can't find anything that I understand enough to translate, so Im asking here. Thank you.

I have tried adding the following code in an attempt to modify the FadeLists function after it has run once (don't want delay on initial run, only on subsequent runs of the function)

```
var myFuncCalls = 0;
function FadeLists($lists, index) {
    myFuncCalls++;
    if(myFuncCalls <= 1) {
        if (index >= $lists.length) index = 0;
        var $currentList = $lists.eq(index);
        $currentList.fadeIn(function() {
            AnimateList($currentList.find("li"), 0, function() { FadeLists($lists, index + 1) });
        })
    } else if(myFuncCalls > 1) {
        console.log('I have been called' + myFuncCalls + 'times');
    }
}

var $allLists = $("ul.contracts")
FadeLists($allLists, 0);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you do not understand your own code?

Comment: I understand what a callback is - 'code that runs after another piece of code has run'. I pieced this code together from some different examples online and want to fully understand how it is structured. Just getting it to this point isn't really good enough if one wants to have command of it.

Comment: In your code, `callback` is a reference to the function being passed in.  In this case, you are passing in `function() { FadeLists($lists, index + 1) }`.  Try wrapping the `FadeLists` in there inside of a `setTimeout` so it happes as part of the callback.

Comment: Please see end of updated question. I can get the code to run first time, and the console message to display each subsequent time. However, I can't get it to delay on the subsequent times it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking something like this? If you want to start the fadeout immediately, you can remove the first setTimeout.

```js
function AnimateList($listItems, index, callback) {
    if (index >= $listItems.length) {
            //hit end of current list, set a timeout to begin fade
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $listItems.closest("ul.contracts").fadeOut(function() {
                    $listItems.css("left","400px").css("opacity",0); //reset
                    //set timeout to allow fade to complete
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        callback(); //next list
                    },500)
                });
            },1000);
        return;
    }


    $listItems.eq(index).animate({left:0, opacity:1}, 1500, function() {
        AnimateList($listItems, index+1, callback)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Matti Price. Much simpler than counting iterations and modifying code based on that number. Curious, would that approach work (see end of my updated question)?

Comment: It probably would "work", you'd be better off with having another parameter passed in that is like "delayStart" or something, and only delaying if that variable is set to true.